# HBase HFiles size generation

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am working on an HBase cluster with 28 region servers.

I have a table, which uses a wide-table definition. The row key is a Hex string, while each row has exactly one column family, which in turn has 80 qualifiers.
Each qualifier name is an int (starting from 1 to 80) and each value is a long.
The table has been presplited into 28 regions, using the classic getHexSplits method defined in the HBase manual [here](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#rowkey.regionsplits).

I have a Map-Reduce job which creates the table, and has to load about 1.8 TB of data in it.

I am using HFileOutputStream to create the HFiles. The problem is that, despite the fact that the job is configured with 28 reducers, and hbase.hregion.max.filesize is set to the default (10GB), I get a lot more(1149 of aprox 1.61 GB each!) HFiles that I expect.

The problem is that, once the table gets created, and the HFiles are being loaded, the table immediately starts both MAJOR and MINOR compactions, which triggers lots of I/O and affect my next Map-Reduce job which does reads from the table. I suppose this happens since there are multiple HFiles per region, and HBase tries to compact them to optimize the reads?

How can I make sure I get a lesser number of HFiles, in order to avoid the compactions? What would be ideal to set as the number of regions for the table, and what other parameters can I set to make sure I get no compactions?
My table is written only once, and then used just for reads.

Comment: Are you saying that each reducer produces multiple hfiles (~41 per reducer)?

Comment: Yes, the Map Reduce Job runs with 28 reducers, yet I get more than 1100 output HFiles. I do not configure the number of reducers, but I think HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad() configures that by looking at the number of table presplit regions.